# How do I write a probability function in JS

Tags: javascript

I am writing some JS and I can't seem to figure out how to write a function that will give a true or false statement back.

The way I want to write it is:

- Loop function 5 times
- on each loop give 1 of 8 random prizes
- then check the probability of getting the prize, e.g 1 out of 10,000.
- One of the loops has to provide with 1 as true

Any help is appreciated.

This is what I have tried, in terms of getting the probability

```js
function prob(n) {
  var old = n - 1;
  var val = (n += 1);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * val) == old;
}
console.log(prob(2));
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a weighted random number. Should have plenty examples on stackoverflow to look at.

Comment: @jarmod I have edited the post, sorry about that :)

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, I will have a look :)

Comment: it current *does* give a boolean value back, so what's not working?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Sorry i missed the final point. I have now edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use these helper functions if I need random

```js
const chance = (percentage) => Math.random() * 100 < percentage;
const getRandomInt = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
const getRandomArbitrary = (min, max) =>
  Math.random() * (max - min) + min;

console.log(chance(50));
console.log(getRandomInt(1, 10));
console.log(getRandomArbitrary(0, 5));

// Full code
const prizes = [{
    name: 'Bear',
    probability: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Car',
    probability: 0.02,
  },
  {
    name: 'Poster',
    probability: 90,
  },
];

let count = 5;
while (count--) {
  const prize = prizes[getRandomInt(0, prizes.length - 1)];
  const win = chance(prize.probability);
  console.log(`Prize: ${prize.name} - Won: ${win}`);
}
```